# Reading Standard Input Into Structures Giving Weird Values

Tags: c, input, struct, stdin

I have a problem where I have to read multiple user inputs (last names) from the standard input separated by a white space.I only know the max input which is 10, but for test cases they could range anywhere from 0-10 inputs. My job is to separate the text from the white space and save the last names for manipulation later.

**Example UserInput From Standard Input**

Smith Paul Joe

I then I have to store "Smith" "Paul" and "Joe" in arrays for manipulation later.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct name{
    char name[100];
};

int main (){

    char user[100];
    int length,i;
    int counter = 0;
    int start = 0;

    fgets(user,sizeof(user),stdin);
    struct name lname[10];
    length = strlen(user);

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){

        if(user[i]==' '){

         strncpy(lname[counter].name, user+start,i -start);
         printf("%s\n",lname[counter].name);
            start = i+1;
            counter++;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Below is a test case where I wrote "I like turtles on the beach" and the output is shown.
[image: Error In Processing]

I know why the last word is not printing, my issue is why does the standard output give me those weird characters? Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: What is supposed to come after the letter 'e' in "like" in memory?

Comment: Please read e.g. [this `strncpy` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy). Pay close attentions that it might not always add the string null terminator!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So if I manually add a null terminator to each structure would that solve the problem?

Comment: As far as I can see with only a quick glance, yes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup that fixed it thank you.

Comment: You should also check the return value of `fgets` and that you don't have more names/words than you have space for. I would also suggest rethinking the naming, e.g., `user` should probably be `buffer` or something, and `struct name` could be `struct user` instead, and then the array `lname` could be `users`… (e.g., compare `users[index].name` to `lname[counter].name`)

Comment: @KaasimShaikh never use `strncpy`, there is almost no use case for this function.

Comment: I think a simple ```struct name lname[10] = {0};``` will fix your problem